# how can I sniff modbus rtu packet with vb code or there are any library for it?

Tags: vb.net

how can I sniff modbus rtu packet with vb code or there are any library for it?

I googled it but I didnt find any thing

Answer (score 0):

This is probably offtopic but I once spent quite a while looking for tools for this very purpose and I have to admit they were not easy to find.

Fortunately, there is a utility that will probably fit your needs: [SerialPCAP](https://github.com/j123b567/SerialPCAP).

It's written in C# but you should be able to port it quite easily. Together with [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/), on Linux you will be able to monitor real-time Modbus RTU traffic.

I'm not affiliated with the developers, I'm just a happy user.